# Unequal rows in CSS grid

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a CSS grid with unequal rows and I cannot make `.feature-block-header` take ONLY as much space as it actually needs. I don't want it to be equal height with `.feature-block-text`. Is there a way of having a flex-grow sort of way on `.feature-block-text` so that it takes whatever space header did not use?

I think I have tried almost every grid row property...

```css
.feature-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 320px auto;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "feature-block-image feature-block-header"
    "feature-block-image feature-block-text";
}

.feature-block-header {
  grid-area: feature-block-header;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.feature-block-image {
  grid-area: feature-block-image;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.feature-block-text {
  grid-area: feature-block-text;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature-block">
  <h2 class="feature-block-header">Header</h2>
  <div class="feature-block-image"></div>
  <div class="feature-block-text">
    <p>Some text within text block</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By adjusting the `grid-template-rows`property, you can adjust the row heights. I just added this property to your code to demonstrate the result.

EDIT: I changed `50px` to `auto` to make it flexible to adjust row content height.

```
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
```

```css
.feature-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 320px auto;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "feature-block-image feature-block-header"
    "feature-block-image feature-block-text";
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.feature-block-header {
  grid-area: feature-block-header;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.feature-block-image {
  grid-area: feature-block-image;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.feature-block-text {
  grid-area: feature-block-text;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature-block">
  <h2 class="feature-block-header">Header</h2>
  <div class="feature-block-image"></div>
  <div class="feature-block-text">
    <p>Some text within text block</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not flexible when it comes to multiline header e.g. mobile view. It's a fixed height.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk My mistake sorry. I changed 50px to auto to make it flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `align-self: start;` to `.feature-block-header`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self

Comment: It doesn't make `.feature-block-text` take the remaining space. It is still in the same position.

Comment: I see, I missed that in the description.